# I have a problem with hibernate. when starting my application it goes very slow, it takes 2 minutes to start the first sessionFactory with hibernate

Tags: java

I have a problem with hibernate.

I am new to hibernate. I am developing a desktop program but I found it interesting to use hibernate as an ORM.

I am using eclipse as IDE. The problem comes when I export my project to .jar and run it on my computer or on another, it takes too long to enter, as far as I can see it is the first sessionFactory that takes too long, I still add my configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/farmaciabd</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>

    <property name="c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
    <property name="c3p0.idle_test_period">20</property><!-- seconds -->
    <property name="c3p0.max_size">5</property>
    <property name="c3p0.max_statements">10</property>
    <property name="c3p0.min_size">3</property>
    <property name="c3p0.timeout">20</property><!-- seconds -->
    <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.use_scrollable_resultset">true</property>
    
    
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>  
    
    <mapping class="modelos.TblAccesos"/>
    <mapping class="modelos.TblArqueocaja"/>
    <mapping class="modelos.TblCiudad"/>
    <mapping class="modelos.TblCertificador"/>
    <mapping class="modelos.TblCompras"/>
    <mapping class="modelos.TblDepartamento"/>
    <mapping class="modelos.TblDetalle"/>
    <mapping class="modelos.TblDetallecompra"/>
    <mapping class="modelos.TblEmpresa"/>
    <mapping class="modelos.TblInventario"/>
    <mapping class="modelos.TblProductos"/>
    <mapping class="modelos.TblProveedores"/>
    <mapping class="modelos.TblSede"/>
    <mapping class="modelos.TblUsuario"/>
    <mapping class="modelos.TblUsuarioAccesos"/>
    <mapping class="modelos.TblVentas"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

y mi POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
   instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
 4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>FarmaciaHibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>Farmacia</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.21</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.14.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
     <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.14.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.14.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.vincenzopalazzo</groupId>
    <artifactId>material-ui-swing</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1_pre-release_6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.swinglabs/swingx -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.swinglabs</groupId>
    <artifactId>swingx</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.jiconfont</groupId>
    <artifactId>jiconfont-swing</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.jiconfont</groupId>
    <artifactId>jiconfont-google_material_design_icons</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>  
    </dependencies>
    </project>
```

Please help!

Comment: how did you determine it is the sessionFactory?

Comment: maybe I determined it in a silly way but, I put a JOptionPane before and after that line.